# How can I extract the last character from a string after I have written in an input?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've a project in laravel and php and in a view I have an input where I write a string of **10** characters, and other input with max value of **1**. When I write a number in the first input the other input must be content the last character from the first input.

For example:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.store', $admin)}}" method="POST">

  <input type="text" maxlength="10" minlength="9" id="number">

  <input type="text" maxlength="1" id="last">

  <input type="submit" value="APPLY CHANGES" onclick="return FillTextBox()">
</form>
```

If I write, **2341325432**, then the second input must be content the value **2**, because **2** is the last character from the first input.

I tried with this but It didn't work completely.

Because in laravel in my controller dd($request->last) return a null value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillTextBox(){
        var string = document.getElementById('number').value;

        document.getElementById('last').value = string.charAt(string.length-1);
    }
</script>
```

Why my function didn't work? I tried to capture with a button the event, o maybe I may try to capture **after I write** a value in the first input.

Comment: Your code appears to work perfectly for me. Are you sure your example isn't doing what you want? Please ensure you have provided a in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Sorry I dont explained very well the question, Now is update.

Comment: another option is to do away with the submit and make it a regular button and submit the form in javascript.

Comment: I have tried with dd($request->last) in my controller and show me a null value. That is the reason because my function in javascript didn't work.

Comment: Your function is correct...

Comment: If you want to get this in php, you must set **name** attribute in html form for your field, and get this name on PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work if you have your JavaScript set to execute [on load](https://jsfiddle.net/2qt4j76f/) or on [DOM ready](https://jsfiddle.net/2qt4j76f/1/) due to load order. If you swap it to be at either the bottom of `<head>` or `<body>` it will work as expected:

```js
function FillTextBox() {
  var string = document.getElementById('number').value;
  document.getElementById('last').value = string.charAt(string.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<form action="new_tab.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" minlength="9" id="number">
  <input type="text" readonly="read" maxlength="1" id="last">
  <input type="submit" value="APPLY CHANGES" onclick="return FillTextBox()">
</form>
```

To prevent this, you should really be making use of **[unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** by adding **[event listeners](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/event-listener.htm)** instead of using the [**`onclick` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var string = document.getElementById('number').value;
  document.getElementById('last').value = string.charAt(string.length - 1);
});
```

```html
<form action="new_tab.php" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" method="POST">
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" minlength="9" id="number">
  <input type="text" readonly="read" maxlength="1" id="last">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="APPLY CHANGES">
</form>
```

In addition to this, as you're making use of `target=_"blank"`, you'll also want to add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to your form to prevent the **["Target Blank" vulnerability](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/)**. I've added this to the above example.

Comment: With pure html and javascript, it's works, but why in laravel, in my controller `dd($request->last);` return a `null` value? That is the reason because I think that the code doesn't work.

Comment: Why does load order matter? The function just has to be loaded before the user clicks on the button. Maybe you're talking about scope?

Comment: Sorry Now I noticed that my error was in my code in my controller in laravel, and not in the function in javascript, the function works well.

Answer (score 1):

I've added **name** attribute to your form fields to grab it on php code:

```
<form action="test.php" target="_blank" method="POST">

  <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="number" minlength="9" id="number">

  <input type="text" maxlength="1" name="last" id="last">

  <input type="submit" value="APPLY CHANGES" onclick="return FillTextBox()">
</form>
```